# Robust Python3 shebang line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shebang

Is there a way to write the shebang line such that it will find the Python3 interpreter, if present?

Naively, from [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) I would expect that `#!/usr/bin/env python3` should work.

However, I've noticed that on some systems where `python` is Python3, they don't provide a `python3` alias. On these systems, you'd need to use `#!/usr/bin/env python` to get Python3.

Is there a robust way to handle this ambiguity? Is there some way to write the shebang line such that it will use `python3` if present, but try `python` if not? (Requiring that end users manually fix their systems to add a `python3` alias is not ideal.)

Comment: If there is none you can always write a small bash script to test availability with `python -V` or testing the return code of python and python3 and then call the app from there.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can see to do this is to provide your own shebang wrapper to call the correct version of python. If you can reliably place the wrapper in a set location you can do this:

Create wrapper script, e.g. /usr/local/bin/python3_wrapper

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="$1"
shift
if which python3 >/dev/null; then
  exec python3 "$cmd" "$@"
elif which python >/dev/null; then
  version=$(python --version 2>&1 | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d. -f1)
  if [[ "$version" == "3" ]]; then
    exec python "$cmd" "$@"
  else
    echo "python is version $version (python3 not found)"
  fi
else
  echo "python3 nor python found"
fi
exit 1
```

Then use the following shebang in your script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3_wrapper
```

Your other option would be to call a python script that works in both version 2 and 3 that then calls your python3 script using the correct executable. If your script is called script.py then rename it to script.py3 and create script.py as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    exe = "python"    # python is version 3.x
else:
    exe = "python3"   # python is not version 3.x so try python3
try:
    os.execvp(exe, [exe, sys.argv[0]+'3'] + sys.argv[1:])
except:
    print(exe, "not found")
sys.exit(1)
```